# C# Data Grid View CheckBox Issue

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm new to C# and have been trying to create a small program which has a connection to an Access Database and pulls all data from it into a Data grid view

![Image of Example Row] https://gyazo.com/9b9fd67847d9a2c5bafd4215e77c37fa

i've put a link to an image showing an example row. It works perfectly except for when i try to actively edit anything in the data grid, nothing will save and update to the Access Database. How would i go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: DataGridView doesn't update your database magically. You need to write code to update your database. Do you have the code that tries to update the database? Could you post it?

Comment: I know it's not magic :), there was a toolbox option which I set to EditOnEnter, I believed this would update my database with an automated sql query when I hit enter, it didn't work so I must be wrong, other than that I haven't tried to manually input data as I was hoping the data grid would have an event that could do it for me, am I completely wrong here?

Comment: If you have filled the DataGridView with a DataTable and an DataAdapter then the easiest way to update your database is through the same adapter instance call to Update method (This has some limitations though, only one table, primary key present in the retrieved data, global instance kept for the Dataadapter)

Comment: When I set up the data grid view the data wizard did it all for me, it asked me for connection type (I used an OleDb connection), it asked for the location of the access database (one table) and i provided it, I simply then selected the table I wanted to show and clicked okay. So how would I access this already existing connection as I didn't code it myself and it isn't in my form code class, sorry if I seem to not understand, this is my first c# / sql project :)

Comment: I see, you are using the wizard. Sorry but I never use those things. You could search on MSDN about that wizard (DataGridView Data Wizard) and check if you have followed all the required steps. Or you can learn to use the bare ADO.NET commands with OleDbConnection. OleDbDataAdapter and DataTable object

Comment: Looks like that's my option, ignore any templates and just learn the good old fashion way, no problem, thanks for the help anyway